# Is it possible in Spring to have a reference to part of another bean?

Tags: java, spring, properties, reference, javabeans

Code:

```
<bean id="bean1" ...
 <property name="Utils">
...
</bean>
```

I would like to do:

```
<bean id="bean2" ...
 <property name="Utils" ref="bean1.Utils"/>
```

Is it possible in Spring? Or something similar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that **Jigar Joshi**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327606/357360)  is what you need - but if not you can use [SpEL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html):

```
<bean id="bean2" ...
 <property name="Utils" value="#{bean1.getUtils()}"/>
```

This is assuming bean1 exposes a `getUtils()` method.

Note that this is less than orthodox and usually not a recommended practice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes

```
<bean id="bean1" ...>
 <property name="Utils" ref="utilBean">
</bean>


<bean id="utilBean" ...>
```

and

```
<bean id="bean2" ...
 <property name="Utils" ref="utilBean"/>
```

Since `utilBean` would be **singleton** both `bean1` and `bean2` would have same instance for property `Utils`

Comment: You assumed that the `part of bean` which OP refers is another bean in same container which is not always true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PropertyPathFactoryBean. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-property-path :

```
<bean id="bean2" ...
  <property name="Utils">
    <bean id="bean1.Utils"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPathFactoryBean"/>
```

This can also use properties from bean1 that are not set by Spring, as long as there's a getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be defined as xml based like;

```
<bean id="bean1">
 <property name="Utils" ref="bean2">
</bean>
```

as annotation based in Java like;

```
@Autowired
Bean2 bean2;
```

Comment: This is not what the OP requested - this is just simple dependency injection.